# How to update all the values of column in a db2 table using python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, db2, pandas-to-sql

I have a table in db2 as below:
**index--------name---------pass**
0----------------A-------------No
1----------------B-------------No
2----------------C-------------No

I need to change it to:
**index--------name---------pass**
0----------------A-------------Yes
1----------------B-------------Yes
2----------------C-------------Yes

This has to be done with sqlalchemy (pandas) pandas.dataframe.to_sql()

like:
df.to_sql('asdad', engine, 'PASDA', if_exists='replace', index=False)

instead of replacing the entire table, i just need change the values in column 'pass' using python preferably without looping(in a one liner).

I need it without creating a temporary table in db and without copying the entire table into a dataframe.

With sqlalchemy: like::

```
metadata = sa.MetaData(schema='XXXXX')
table = sa.Table('Table', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
query = table.update().values(PASS = 'YES').where(table.Index<5)
results = conn.execute(query)
```

Im getting an error in where part as Table does not have attribute index, what should i actually give there?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use the `df.to_sql` function here in order to perform an `UPDATE` sql function

Comment: Did you try `where(index < 5)`?